# How do I get the list of all apps installed in a SharePoint web application?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin

Is there a SharePoint API that would let me get a list of installed apps along with their hashes? I have some external web sites that are making REST calls to a SharePoint hosted app using cross domain library, but the problem is every time I reinstall the sharepoint app, its hash changes, so i have to manually update its URL in the external sites' JS code. I am looking into ways to automate that.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out:

```
SPAppCatalog.GetAppInstances(parentWeb);
```